# Stripe Payment: undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have an application that I am testing stripe payments on.  Right now, I am trying to configuring the charge so that it takes the price from another model (pin.price) and charges it correctly.  So far, I am running into the following error message:

**NoMethodError in ChargesController#create
undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass**

app/controllers/charges_controller.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = (@pin.price * 100).floor

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
    end
end
```

app/controllers/pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :bid]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  .....

    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :price, :image, :manufacturer, :model)
    end
end
```

app/db/migrate

```
class AddPriceToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :price, :decimal
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure the error is coming from "@amount = (@pin.price * 100).floor" but I am just not sure how to better express this amount so each pin's price isn't static but matches to its current inputted value in the database.

EDIT: Including form with link to stripe payment code here:

```
 <%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargesForm' do %>
              <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>  
              <button id="btn-buy" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>   I want this!</button>

              <script>
                  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                    key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
                    token: function(token, arg) {
                      document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
                      document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
                      document.getElementById("chargesForm").submit();
                    }
                  });
                   document.getElementById('btn-buy').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    handler.open({
                      name: '<%= @pin.manufacturer %>',
                      description: '<%= @pin.description %>',
                      amount: '<%= (@pin.price * 100).floor %>'
                  });
                  e.preventDefault();
                 })
              </script>
          <% end %>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: At `ChargesController#create` variable `@pin` is not initialized (`@pin == nil`). You need to add something like `@pin = Pin.find(params[:id])` or `@pin = Pin.build(...)`.

Comment: Just initialized the variable with @pin = Pin.find(params[:id]) and got the error message: "Couldn't find Pin without an ID".  Not sure, why is this happening?

Comment: You just need to find out what is `@pin`. Do you create it or retrieve from database? I can be more specific, if there will be more code from your models/controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your charges controller `@pin` isn't assigned to anything and therefore has a value of `nil` hence the error.

You therefore need to assign `@pin` to a value before you call price on it. In order to do that you need to figure out how you are going to get the pin from the DB or whether or not you create it.

One solution could be to pass in the id of the pin in the request path, e.g.

```
create_charge_path(pin_id: 123)
```

EDIT: This doesn't have to be hardcoded to 123 it can be whatever pin you like, just depends on where it's being called from. E.g. if you are calling from another controller action that has already loaded a particular pin from the database you could do:

```
create_charge_path(pin_id: pin.id)
```

Then in your `ChargesController`

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def create
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = (@pin.price * 100).floor

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
    end
end
```

This will then assign `@pin` to a pin with a database ID of `123`.

Comment: Where would you pass in the id of the pin in the request path?  I'm trying to see if there is a more scalable way to do this instead of assigning @pin and all its instances to only one id in the database.

Comment: So whatever method, or button or link calls the ChargesController#create method, that is where you would pass in the PIN ID. Also, this won't be a global assign - it will only assign `@pin` to the passed in pin id. See my edit for clarification

Comment: So for some reason this is not working.  I've added more of my code with the button that calls ChargesController, I believe -- not sure if I adding another hidden field text with the path you recommended would work.